# Why does text appear off canvas in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

When I select the type tool and click in the center of the canvas, the text always appears outside the canvas. This has always happened on my work PC and I have never had the issue at home. How can I reset the type tool to get it to appear where I click inside the canvas?

[image: Text appearing outside canvas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a guess:

You have a big negative first line indent in the Paragraph panel; like this:

[image]

Set it to zero and you get:

[image]

Comment: This worked! I didn't even think to check the paragraph panel. Thank you for the help :)